# Stored procedure which returns results of multiple entities

Tags: entity-framework

Hi I have a stored procedure which returns result of some fields of multiple tables . can i map the result to associated tables (without using complex types)?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box implementation allows you mapping only to flat structures. So either your stored procedures returns single mapped entity type or you need a complex / custom type. It doesn't allow mapping to relations.